# Creating .nupkg from .csproj file in Visual Studio 2017: Properties not updated correctly

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

I use Visual Studio 2017, MSBuild version 15.4.8.50001.

I want to create a `.nupkg` file by reading directly from my `.csproj` file. Following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/msbuild-targets), I updated the **first** `PropertyGroup` in my `.csproj` file to this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{24BAFE05-8B92-4EAA-8790-03C0768ACC57}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>D</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>D</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <PackageId>MyCompany.Nuget.D</PackageId>
    <PackageVersion>1.0</PackageVersion>
    <Author>Me</Author>
    <Title>Nuget Experiment Project D</Title>
    <Description>Top-level class in the diamond dependency structure</Description>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I opened the command prompt, navigated to the folder containing my `.csproj` file, and ran the command `nuget spec`, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package).

However, the resulting `.nuspec` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://LICENSE_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>http://PROJECT_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://ICON_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

As you can see, none of the properties I defined in my `.csproj` file are correctly populated in my `.nuspec` file.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I initially accepted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47137397/3559686), but now I don't think it is correct.

I changed the `PackageVersion` property in my `.csproj` file to `2.0`:

```
<PackageVersion>2.0</PackageVersion>
```

If, as the answer claims, the properties in `.nuspec` are indeed updated during packing by reading from my `.csproj` file, the new `.nupkg` file should have the name `MyCompany.Nuget.D.2.0.0.nupkg`.

However, the new `.nupkg` file is still named `D.1.0.0.nupkg`:

[image]

**EDIT:** I followed the instructions included in [Leo-MSFT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47150812/3559686), and changed the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file to the following:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("NewD")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("Some dummy description")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("MyCompany.Me")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("NewD")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright MyCompany 2017")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("3.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec#replacement-tokens), `$id$` is retrieved from the `AssemblyName` field in my `.csproj` file, and `$version$`, `$author$`, `$description$` and `$copyright$` are retrieved from `AssemblyInfo.cs`. For that reason, **I also updated the `AssemblyName` field in my `.csproj` file to `MyCompany.NugetTest.D`**.

I navigated to the folder containing my `.sln` file, and ran `nuget spec "D\D.csproj" as suggested in the answer. The generated`nuspec`` file looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>D\D.csproj</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Me</authors>
    <owners>Me</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://LICENSE_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>http://PROJECT_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://ICON_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="SampleDependency" version="1.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

I changed `id` to `SuperUniqueD`, and ran `nuget pack D.csproj`. The package `D.3.0.0.nupkg` was then created.

Why is the package still named `D`? Shouldn't it be named `MyCompany.NugetTest.D` if the value is read from the `AssemblyName` field in the `.csproj` file (according to documentation), or `NewD` if it is read from `AssemblyInfo.cs`?

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved your issue? If not, Please let me know the latest information about this issue.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT Hello, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I didn't get a chance to test your solution yesterday because I was ill and didn't go to work. I shall test your solution today and update ASAP. :-)

Comment: @Leo-MSFT I have tested your solution but unfortunately the result was not quite what I hoped for. I have updated my question with my latest results. Did I misunderstand any of your instructions?

Comment: Where did you change the `Id` to  `SuperUniqueD`? You should change it in project file. I have updated my answer with more detail info, you can check if it helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> none of the properties I defined in my .csproj file are correctly populated in my .nuspec file. What am I doing wrong?

That because you navigated to the folder containing your `.csproj` file, you should **navigate to the folder containing your .sln file** or include full path in your command without navigation, the command like:

1. Navigate to solution folder:

   `C:\Workspaces\NuGet Experimentation\D>nuget spec "D\D.csproj"`
2. Without navigation:

   `C:\Users\Admin>nuget spec "C:\Workspaces\NuGet Experimentation\D\D\D.csproj"`

The tokens in the form `$<token>$` are be replaced during the packaging process with values from the project's `Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs` file. The settings info of this file are included in the `.sln` file. If you navigate to the folder containing your .csproj file, NuGet could not find the location of `AssemblyInfo.cs`, so NuGet will use the default value `$<token>$` instead of the value from the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file. Using above methods, you will get the `.nuspec` file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>C:\Workspaces\NuGet Experimentation\D\D\D.csproj</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Admin</authors>
    <owners>Admin</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://LICENSE_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>http://PROJECT_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://ICON_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="SampleDependency" version="1.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

In order to select a package ID that is unique across nuget.org, you also need to modify the Id of `.nuspec` manually. See [Create the .nuspec package manifest file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package#create-the-nuspec-package-manifest-file) for more detail info.

For the **Edit** question:

> However, the new .nupkg file is still named D.1.0.0.nupkg.

Just like answer the first question "***The tokens in the form $$ are be replaced during the packaging process with values from the project's Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs file.***"

So if you want to generate the package with update version, you should update the Assembly Version in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file, then use the pack cammand line to generate the nuget package: `nuget pack xx.csproj`.

See [Replacement tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec#replacement-tokens) for more info about tokens.

**Update for Edit**:

> I changed id to SuperUniqueD, and ran nuget pack D.csproj. The package
>   D.3.0.0.nupkg was then created.

Since you are using the command: `nuget pack D.csproj`, you should change the Id in your project file rather than `.nuspec` file:

[image]

If you changed the Id in the `.nuspec`, you should pack it with `.nuspec` file: `nuget pack D.csproj.nuspec`

Comment: Thanks for your update. As mentioned in my update I changed ``AssemblyName`` in ``.csproj`` to ``MyCompany.NugetTest.D``, but the generated ``.nupkg`` file is not named as such...

Comment: @MY_G, Confused. You said you changed the `id` to `SuperUniqueD`, now you changed the AssemblyName in .csproj to `MyCompany.NugetTest.D`, What are you actually doing? And what is the generate package name? If you still could not resolve you issue, you can share me a gif or video for detail info. BTW, try to update the nuget.exe version.

Comment: Hello, I have changed ``AssemblyName`` to ``SuperUniqueD``, to be consistent with my ``nuspec`` file. So now *both* ``AssemblyName`` in ``D.csproj`` and ``id`` in the ``nuspec`` file is ``SuperUniqueD``. I am also using the latest stable version of ``nuget.exe``. Now the generated ``.nupkg`` has the name ``SuperUniqueD``, as expected. However, its version number is still ``1.0.0``, even though I have already updated ``AssemblyVersion`` to ``3.0.0.0`` in my ``AssemblyInfo.cs`` file...

Comment: @MY_G, you may pack the .nuspec file, there is a little issue about the .nuspec file. If you update the AssemblyVersion to 3.0.0.0, then you generate the .nuspec file still with the version 1.0.0, you need manually change the `<version>1.0.0</version>` to `<version>3.0.0</version>`. Or you can directly pack the `D.csproj` after change the AssemblyVersion to 3.0.0.0. BTW, BTW, Did my answer resolve your question, if yes, you can mark it as answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The properties in the `.nuspec` file are indeed updated from your `.csproj` file properties. However, there is one exception in this case. When generating NuGet packages from projects, the version of the NuGet package corresponds to the `Assembly Version`. So, if within your project, you open the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file and update the `Assembly Version` to `2.0.0.0` from `1.0.0.0` and build the project, the resultant package that gets generated on `nuspec pack` will have the name with the version 2.0.0.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is correct nuspec properties.

This `$id$` and other tokens are replaced with the values from the .csproj file at packing time.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I have to un-accept your answer for the reason given in my update.

Comment: Okey. No problem.